# Java question about instance variables vs. local variables

Tags: java, android

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm confused about what's going on. I declare `Workout mWorkout;` as an instance variable at the top of my class. Up until this point, it hasn't been initialized.

This code works: `createWorkout` returns a `Workout object`, which is stored in the local variable `test`, and then the instance variable `mWorkout` is set from that.

```
public void startWorkout() {
    Workout test = workoutFactory.createWorkout(); 
    mWorkout = test;
}
```

Whereas this code doesn't:

```
public void startWorkout() {
    mWorkout = workoutFactory.createWorkout(); 
}
```

`mWorkout` remains `null` even though `createWorkout` is still returning a `Workout` object.

Above code is slightly simplified for clarity.

Comment: Something tells me you've missed something in your simplification of your code.

Comment: I think your code might be oversimplified, because those two examples should be functionally identical.

Comment: Can you show your whole class and WorkoutFactory.

Comment: Concur. We are missing the context to see how those two statements are different.

Comment: This code cannot exhibit the behavior you describe - you have over-simplified it. Provide an actual example, and we can investigate it.

Comment: Hmm, got back to the code this morning, rolled it back to the non-working version, which is now working for some reason. I've been getting weird errors like this in Eclipse, which seem to go away after a cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try qualifying `mWorkout` with `this`.

```
this.mWorkout = workoutFactory.createWorkout();
```

My assumption is that you have defined a local `mWorkout` that's [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your instance variable with the same name.

Comment: This is a good answer, and the most likely reason (in general).

I got back to the code this morning, rolled it back to the non-working version, which is now working for some reason. I've been getting weird errors like this in Eclipse, which seem to go away after a cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that somewhere in the non-working version of `startWorkout` you have declared a method-scope instance of `mWorkout` which is masking the instance field. If you tried `this.mWorkout = ...` you might get a different result.